# How to get / initialize / unproxy data from session.load(E.class, id) in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

How to get / initialize / unproxy data from `session.load(E.class, id)` in Hibernate??
No (e.g. `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` ...)

```
Hibernate.initialize(el) return new property "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}


try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {

    session.beginTransaction();

    final Employee el = session.load(E.class, id);//Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy

    Hibernate.initialize(el);
    Employee el2 =  Hibernate.unproxy(el, E.class); // "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    return el; //"hibernateLazyInitializer": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if no "unproxy" you will get error

"message": "Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy [***] - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy [****] - no Session (through reference chain: com.***.E$HibernateProxy$Zq7mcdJl[\"firstName\"])",

Need use:

```
E el =  Hibernate.unproxy(session.load(E.class, id), E.class);
```